# Matching an IP address within a specified range using awk

Tags: awk, patterns

In a list of IP addresses separated by newlines, I'm trying to match only on internal 172 addresses (i.e. 172.16.x - 172.31.x). I tried this but it isn't working:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^172.[1-3][6-9]|[0-1]/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not something like `awk -F. '$1 == 172 && ($2 >= 16 && $2 <= 31)'`  instead of struggling with numeric range in regex?

Comment: While I really like that idea, it won't work in a stringed conditional statement in comma-delimited file where I'm comparing specific fields. But that isn't specified as a requirement in the answer - so great idea!

Comment: you can always split fields inside awk, and I was curious why grep wasn't used.. seems you have other processing in awk :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `^172.[1-3][6-9]|[0-1]` matches things like

```
172x39
40
```

the latter because you match anything with a 0 or a 1 in the first field.

You need to change the `.` to `\.` to make it a literal dot, you need to introduce grouping and you need a better pattern.

```
 ^172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\.
```